# Combining corresponding elements of lists in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have two lists
A=[a,b,c,d]
B=[1,2,3,4]
How can I merge A and B in a nested list of corresponding elements of A and B in Python
My outcome will be [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4]].
Please help me. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4]

C = [list(x) for x in zip(A,B)]
```

Result:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]
```